# Modifying the EXIF meta data and exporting it

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, exif

```
import exifread
f = open('manu.JPEG', 'rb')
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
tags['EXIF SceneType'] = "Manu"
tags['EXIF ExposureMode'] = "Prakash"
tags['Image Make'] = "Georgian"
tags.save('mjp.jpg', 'jpeg', exif=exif_bytes)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-48afdf003b60> in <module>()
      2 tags['EXIF ExposureMode'] = "Prakash"
      3 tags['Image Make'] = "Georgian"
----> 4 tags.save('mjp.jpg', 'jpeg', exif=exif_bytes)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I converted a jpeg image file to a dictionary and made some changes to its metadata. I now want to download the image file with the new changes in its meta data. I tried using ".save" method but it is throwing an error.